# What are the 2 protrusions next to the fore ground lights on the Tu-22M3?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-systems, bomber, strategic-bomber

Here's a reference image :

[image]

What are those 2 spokes coming out next to the ground lights ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They appear to be pitot tubes, part of the air data system.